# Remove a column from a matrix in GNU Octave

Tags: matrix, octave

In GNU Octave, I want to be able to remove specific columns from a matrix.  In the interest of generality.  I also want to be able to remove specific rows from a matrix.

Suppose I have this:

```
mymatrix = eye(5)

mymatrix =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1
```

I want to remove columns 2 and 4, but when I remove column 2, the position of column 4 has moved to column 3, and that makes my head hurt.  There has to be a better way!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**GNU Octave delete Columns 2 and 4 from a Matrix**

```
mymatrix = eye(5); 
mymatrix(:,[2,4]) = []; 
disp(mymatrix)
```

Prints:

```
1   0   0
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
0   0   1
```

**GNU Octave delete Rows 2 and 4 from a Matrix:**

```
mymatrix = eye(5); 
mymatrix([2,4],:) = [];
disp(mymatrix)
```

Prints:

```
1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   1
```

**Time complexity**

GNU Octave's CPU complexity for slicing and broadcasting here is a fast linear time `O(n * c)` where n is number of rows and c a constant number of rows that remain.  It's C level single-core vectorized but not parallel.

**Memory complexity**

Working memory complexity is linear: `O(n * 2)` C makes a clone of the two objects, iterates over every element, then deletes the original.

The only time speed will be a problem is if your matrices are unrealistically wide, tall, or have a number of dimensions that blow out your fast memory, and speed is limited by the transfer speed between disk and memory.

Answer (score 77):

In case you don't know the exact number of columns or rows you can use the magic "end" index, e.g.:

```
mymatrix(:,2:end)  % all but first column

mymatrix(2:end,:)  % all but first row
```

This also allows you to slice rows or columns out of a matrix without having to reassign it to a new variable.

Comment: so much cleaner :D

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 14):

The reverse method of doing this:

```
columns_you_want_to_keep = [1, 3, 5]
new_matrix = my_matrix(:,columns_you_want_to_keep)
```

Answer (score 9):

### How to remove multiple columns in octave:

How to remove columns 2 and 4:

```
columns_to_remove = [2 4];
matrix(:,columns_to_remove)=[]
```

Illustrated:

```
mymatrix = eye(5)
mymatrix =

   1   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   1



columns_to_remove = [2 4];

mymatrix(:,columns_to_remove)=[]


mymatrix =

   1   0   0
   0   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   0
   0   0   1
```