# Splitting matrices and vectors in GNU Octave to get rows not extracted

Tags: vector, matrix, octave

In GNU Octave, I can use the following code to get every 5th row of X.

How do I get another matrix `X_2` that consists of the rows that have not been extracted or left behind in `X`?

```
X = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11]
ix = ( 5 : 5 : size(X,1) )
X_1 = X( ix , : )
```

I want `X_2` to have everything but 5 and 10.  Is this possible?

Comment: X can be either a matrix, e.g. 500 rows and 50 columns, or a single column, 500 row vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Gnu Octave, Get every nth row of a matrix/vector:**

```
X = [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11]
ix = ( 5 : 5 : size(X,1) )
```

prints:

```
ix =
    5   10
```

Now, remove rows from the original matrix which will give you a list of the rows not extracted.

Example, remove row 5 and 10 from X:

```
X([5,10],:) = []
```

Prints X with 5 and 10 missing:

```
X =

    1
    2
    3
    4
    6
    7
    8
    9
   11
```

So that proves concept.  Use your ix variable to do it on the specified columns:

```
X(ix,:) = []
```

That will make X a list of the rows that have not been extracted.  If you need to not disturb the original, make a copy of X and put it into another variable before you do this.  Then assign `X_2 = X;`

**Source:**

[Remove a column from a matrix in GNU Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12390419/gnu-octave-how-to-remove-a-column-from-a-matrix)